# Laravel: Remove redundant tags in polymorphy

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I used the Laravel documentation to build a [polymorphic structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) many to many relations.

Tables structure :

```
 posts
   id - integer
   name - string

tags
  id - integer
  name - string

taggables
  tag_id - integer
  taggable_id - integer
  taggable_type - string
```

I can use the `sync` method to add and remove records to the *taggables* (NOT *tags*) table:
 `$post->tags()->sync([tags_id])`
 there are cases that a tag is in *tags* table. Still, no posts are associated with it , so the *tags* table will blow up more and more; what's the best approach to delete tags (from *tags* table) that doesn't have any taggable model (here Post) assigned to them?

Comment: Be more specific if you wish a right answer. Please post your code fragments.